# how to detect an object when dropped on top of another

Tags: kineticjs

I am trying to detect a drag and dropped object. Consider circle object being dragged and dropped inside a rectangle, how can I detect the circle, from rectangle. I am not sure whether kineticjs provides an event detector for this kind. Kindly help me how can I detect the circle object, from rectangle object.

Comment: am not clear what do you mean by detecting circle from rectangle... however, while dropping circle you can easily detect rectangle using the getIntersection method.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect which shapes in a layer that intersects a point ([1](http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Container.php#getIntersections)), maybe that is the closest answer to the question.

```
var shapes = mylayer.getIntersections(point)
```